# DD-WRT with native IPv6

Tags: dd-wrt, ipv6

My ISP provides native IPv6 support (ie. I can plug in my computer straight into the WAN and get an IPv6 address).  However I can not get this working on DD-WRT.  When I enable IPv6 and radvd in DD-WRT, the router gets in IPv6 address, but the devices on my LAN do not.
I tried looking at the DD-WRT wiki, but this only displayed instructions for tunneling or other methods where native support isn't available.  I found a small amount of sites thorough searching, but none of the methods these sites described gave my computers each a global IPv6 address.  In addition, SSHing into the router using ping6 on sites such as ipv6.google.com causes "host unreachable" errors.

Has anyone using DD-WRT configured a successful setup with native IPv6?

I am using a Netgear WNDR3700 v2, with DD-WRT build 17201

Comment: What router are you using?

Comment: I'm using a Netgear WNDR3700 v2, with DD-WRT build 17201.

Comment: thanks, I added it to the question for you so it will be easier for others to help you :)

Comment: Does your ISP assign you a single address or a /64 subnet?

Answer (score 3):

“Native” IPv6 is provided by ISPs using a protocol called DHCPv6-PD (Prefix Delegation). This requires that your router sends a DHCPv6 request to the ISP to ask for a prefix, then uses the prefix that it received to give out addresses to the computers on your lan.

DD-WRT does not currently include the tools required for this to function, although you may be able to get it working by manually installing additional tools and running a startup script.

Answer (score 2):

IPv6 only provides autoconfiguration for hosts, not for routers. So your router, as a host on your ISP's network, is getting an IPv6 address from your provider. But as the router for your network, it is not getting a subnet assigned that it can advertise for use on your LAN.

You need a /64 subnet assigned to you by your ISP. Once you configure that subnet for your LAN interface (and in `radvd.conf`) and enable `radvd`, autoconfiguration should work on your LAN.

You got the native support working correctly. Your router is now an IPv6 device. You just need to do the LAN portion, and that is independent of whether the router's connection is native or tunneled.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as you, you need to set the ISP modem to bridge mode, and then set your dd-wrt router to use pppoe in the setup page, enter you user name and password, and then enable ipv6 with prefix delegation.